# Restoring the exact state of a linux install to a different laptop with different sized drives and other hardware

Tags: linux, backup, snapshot

I have a computer running LInux that has already been used and settled into, with packages installed, browser profiles, etc, etc.  The drive is 60gb, and it has a swap partition and an ext4 root partition.

I need to move this profile to a different computer with a bigger drive.

How should I go about this?  My inclination would be to shut it down, boot a live linux system, dd the whole 60gb drive to a file, boot the other one to a live system, then dd the file to its bigger drive.

Would this work? I know that it wouldn't with windows, but I believe this is an artificially imposed limitation from Microsoft.  Is this correct, or is Linux similarly limited?

If not, how could I go about this? Would clonezilla work, or would the hardware disparities prevent it from working?

Answer (score 0):

This would end up with the 60gb drive replicated on the 320gb, with the partitions the same size (so the same free space). You could then add a partition to use up the remaining space (perhaps move /home to a hew partition, as this tends to be the big one).

Alternatively, mount the 320GB as a usb drive, partition it as you want it, then rsync everything over from one drive to the other.

This is something you definitely cannot do with Windows, but you can with linux. The only things you'd need to do is re-install grub and ensure grub.cfg made sense for when you install it as a primary drive.  And make sure /etc/fstab is referencing the right partitions afterwards (does manjero use uuids?)

So the answer to your question is "yes" you *can* just copy linux from one drive to another, and making it work is fairly easy if you are familiar with the above.

Comment: The unused space doesn't bother me.  Are you on IRC or anything, or would you mind helping me through the process?

Comment: I'd be concerned about making it boot, since I know just about nothing about configuring grub...

Comment: And, yes, I see UUIDs for both sda1 and sda2 in my fstab, which are swap and /.

Comment: Sorry I have to go out, so your first suggestion will be fine, to dd the entire drive from one to another (via a file if you want), then you can fix up the partitions afterwards.

Comment: Ok, but when you get back or have a chance, could you let me know what fixing up the partitions will entail?  I guess, worst case, I can just ask around on IRC for advice on 1) fixing fstab, 2) installing grub, 3) fixing grub.cfg to make sense.  Those should be easy to get help with, right?

Thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time where I work. What I generally do is just perform an rsync. Boot into something like the sysreq cd:

http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

Or Ubuntu or any other live disk. Open the terminal and type the following:

```
mkdir /mnt/old
mkdir /mnt/new

mount /dev/sdax /mnt/old
mount /dev/sdbx /mnt/new
```

You'll also want to mount any other special partitions like sdb2 for /home or something. And then just do a normal rsync

```
 rsync -Pav  --exclude=/mnt/old/dev --exclude=/mnt/old/proc --exclude=/mnt/old/sys  /mnt/old /mnt/new/
```

One this is finished we'll need to chroot and do the the grub thing.

```
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/new/dev
mount -t proc none /mnt/new/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/new/sys
chroot /mnt/sysimage /bin/bash
grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab
rm -f /boot/grub/device.map 
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda
```

So this should work...or it will destroy everything. Enjoy!

P.S. I dont believe this will work with Windows

Comment: I think there might be a problem in the grub part. The new disk is mounted to /dev/sdb, but you do grub-install to /dev/sda. Also the chroot, shouldn't that be into the /mnt/new?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the two partition tables: are of they of the same (MS-DOS/GPT) type, or of different type?

If you are happy with carrying over from your old system an MS-DOS partition table, then dd'ing the disk is fine; just make sure that the new system BIOS knows that you are using the compatibility mode for old disks.

Same thing if you are migrating from GPT to GPT system (I doubt this is your case, but I write this for other possible readers).

If instead you have decided to migrate from MS-DOS to GPT partition tables, you cannot dd the disk. The reason is that GPT partition table stores information after the (protective) MBR (and at the end of the disk, but this presents little problem). So, in order to accommodate the new GPT structure after the protective MBR, you should move or re-size your first partition, which is both time-consuming and dangerous for the integrity of your data. In this case, rsync'ing the disks is by far your best solution.

As for hardware compatibility, there should be few problems. By and large, udev takes care of anything, except that you might have some components which require special care. For instance, you may pass from one system where the wifi driver is open-source, to another where instead it requires proprietary software. For instance, you may have to install firmware for your driver. Or, you may have to install the NVidia proprietary drivers for your brand new NVidia card.

It is also possible that you need to re-configure your X server, to adapt it to your new hardware. This is certainly true if you have introduced a new card, with 2D/3D acceleration, because this will require something other than the usual vesa driver.

```
 sudo Xorg :0 -configure
```

will take care of that.

Occasionally, even ethernet connections may require an unusual driver. Though uncommon, this is especially annoying because it may leave you without connections. To allow for this, I suggest you take a peek at how the new pc will do under Linux with a live distro before moving the old system onto it. Just take a note of which drivers the live distro is using for both ethernet and wifi connections, download then onto the old system, and you will have a smooth ride.

As for the possibility of moving Windows to a new system this way, I have never tried it (I never use Windows). However, Windows is proprietary software, and the kind of move you are contemplating essentially amounts to increasing the number of systems running under the same license. For FOSS this is no problem, but I am sure that the owners of proprietary software (Windows and Apple, for instance; but also the owners of all paid applications) have taken measures to prevent this. It might be different if you intend to transfer your license, in which case I am sure some of this software grants a considerable leeway (but once again I cannot talk for Windows out of my own experience).